# Making a Selection with Conditions Set Over Three Tables

Tags: sql, postgresql

There are three tables in question for the query I'm trying to build.

One table has entries of projects associated with a username that is working on that project.

**Table1**
`| id | ... | userName | ... |`

Another table has all the users saved in it with their respective email and job type

**Table 2**
`| id | ... | jobTypeId | email | ... |`

The last table has a list of job type ids with their job name

**Table 3**
`| jobTypeId | jobTypeName |`

1. How would I be able to only select **projects** from **Table 1** where the **userName** when compared to the **email** in **Table 2** are users with **jobTypeIds** from **Table 3** equal to a certain value (ex. "2")
2. How do I compare userName from **Table 1** to email from **Table 2** without incorporating the @whatever.com part of it; only compare the beginning of the email to the username

**Example Data**

**Table 1**

```
| id | ... | userName | ... |  
| 1  |     | bDover   |     |  
| 2  |     | dLong    |     |  
| 3  |     | eEddy    |     |  
| 4  |     | dLong    |     |  
| 5  |     | eEddy    |     |  
| 6  |     | bDover   |     |  
| 7  |     | dLong    |     |  
| 8  |     | eEddy    |     |  
| 9  |     | dLong    |     |  
| 10 |     | dLong    |     |
```

**Table 2**

```
| id | ... | jobTypeId | email                    | ... |  
| 1  |     | 1         | bdover@whatever.com      |     |  
| 2  |     | 2         | dLong@whatever.com       |     |  
| 3  |     | 2         | eEddy@whatever.com       |     |  
| 4  |     | 3         | ...@whatever.com         |     |
```

**Table 3**

```
| jobTypeId | jobTypeName |
| 1         | Student     |
| 2         | Teacher     |
| 1         | Admin       |
```

**Expected Result (with jobTypeId = 2)**

```
| projectId | userName |  
| 2         | dLong    |  
| 3         | eEddy    |  
| 4         | dLong    |  
| 5         | eEddy    |  
| 7         | dLong    |  
| 8         | eEddy    |  
| 9         | dLong    |  
| 10        | dLong    |
```

Comment: i guess you start by building us a data and the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

You may give this a try:

```
SELECT
t1.id as ProjectID, t1.userName

FROM
TABLE1 AS t1, 
TABLE2 AS t2, 
TABLE3 AS t3

WHERE
TRIM(t1.userName) = TRIM(split_part(t2.email, "@", 1))
&& t2.jobTypeId = t3.jobTypeId
&& t3.jobTypeId = 2

GROUP BY
ProjectID
```

This assumes Postgres split_part() works as well as SUBSTRING_INDEX() as MySQL would.

EDIT 2:  If you have fewer rows for table2.jobTypeId = 2 then your WHERE clause should look like this:

```
WHERE
t3.jobTypeId = 2
&& t3.jobTypeId = t2.jobTypeId
&& TRIM(split_part(t2.email, "@", 1)) = TRIM(t1.userName)
```

EDIT:  I added TRIM just in case the formatting of the data may contain whitespace on the username and email.  And here's more information on using SPLIT_PART() in Postgres: http://dataiseverything.blogspot.com/2015/01/equivalent-of-substringindex-in-mysql.html

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want:

```
select t1.projectid, t1.username
from table1 t1 join
     table2 t2
     on t2.email like t1.username || '@%'
where t2.jobtypeid = 2;
```

You don't need `table3` because you are comparing job type ids, not the names.

You should also fix the data model, so `table1` uses the id in `table2` for the `join`, rather than comparing user names and emails.